# TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable with OrderedDict and multiple inheritance

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, initialization, multiple-inheritance, init

Following code with multiple inheritance and a dictionary class, it gives this mysterious error:

`'dict' object is not callable`

but only in the second time i call `dump_settings()`, not the first.

What's this `'dict'` is related to ?

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Dumpable(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dump_settings = None
        super().__init__()

    def dump_settings(self, settings ):
        self.dump_settings = settings
        pass


class ItemSet(OrderedDict, Dumpable):
    def __init__(self , allow_substitution : bool = False ):
        super(OrderedDict, self).__init__()
        super(Dumpable,  self).__init__()
        # also substituting two calls above with the
        # following, do not change behavior:
        # super().__init__()
        self.allow_substitution = allow_substitution
        pass

    def dump_settings(self,settings):
        super().dump_settings(settings)
        pass

itemset = ItemSet()
output = open("output.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
d= dict( output = output , html = False )
print(repr(d))
# this call seems to have no problems:
itemset.dump_settings(d)
print(repr(d))
# note that the given error "'dict' object is not callable"
# has nothing to do with 'd' param because if you change
# in the followin the 'd' with a non-dictionary object,
# the error remains, for example:
# itemset.dump_settings('hello')
itemset.dump_settings(d)
output.close()
```

**NOTE**: the error is not related to `d` variable (that is a `dictionary` too)  because if you change it with a non-dictionary object, the error remains, for example:

`itemset.dump_settings('hello')`

I tried both `Python` version `3.5.2 for linux` and `3.8.3 for Windows`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are replacing your dump_settings method with the dictionary, So when you go to call dump_settings the next time, its a dict now and not a method and like the error says 'dict' is not callable.

Remember methods are just attributes of your class. So after you create your itemset object. itemset.dump_settings attribute points to the method. However when you call dump_settings. You then go on to do self.dump_settings = settings (where settings is the dict you gave it). So now itemset.dump_settings is a dict and not a method.

```py
print(f"itemset.dump_settings, type: {type(itemset.dump_settings)}, {itemset.dump_settings}")
itemset.dump_settings(d)
print(f"itemset.dump_settings, type: {type(itemset.dump_settings)}, {itemset.dump_settings}")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
itemset.dump_settings, type: <class 'method'>, <bound method ItemSet.dump_settings of ItemSet()>
itemset.dump_settings, type: <class 'dict'>, {'output': <_io.TextIOWrapper name='output.txt' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>, 'html': False}
```

If you want to save the dict you need to give it a name in your class thats not already the name of a method.

```py
    def dump_settings(self, settings):
        self.dump_settings_dict = settings
```

Answer (score 0):

found solution, very easy:

there is a conflict because in `Dumpable` class the `dump_settings` it is both a class variable and a method name.

renaming one of them, solves the issue.

Comment: Yeah thats what i wrote in my answer about 10 mins ago. The key thing to note is that there is no only class attributes, so variables and methods are both just attributes of the class. so cannot have the same name